# Reformating associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

To be more specific I want to turn the following array into an associative one. The original array is indexed like [0],[1],[2],…[n]. The function I used was **Set::combine** of Cakephp but I couldn't recreate all three levels of the desired associative array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ACCOUNTS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => A
                )

            [HEADERS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => B                
                )

            [COLUMNS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => C
                    [id] => 8
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ACCOUNTS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => A1
                )

            [HEADERS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => B1                
                )

            [COLUMNS] => Array
                (
                    [description] => C1
                    [id] => 9
                )

        )       
)
```

The array I want to end up is the following associative array:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => Array
                (
                    [C] => 8
                )
        )
    [A1] => Array
        (
            [B1] => Array
                (
                    [C1] => 9
                )
        )       
)
```

I can't recreate all (3) levels of the array above.

Comment: be more specific. I dint get, how did u obtain the above values. Are these Values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:

```
$newarray = array($first['ACCOUNTS']['description'] => array($first['HEADERS']['description']  => array($first['COLUMNS']['description'] => $first['COLUMNS']['id'])));
```

So if you run the following it gives what you want:

```
$first = array(
 'ACCOUNTS' => array('description' => 'A'),
 'HEADERS' => array('description' => 'B'), 
 'COLUMNS' => array('description' => 'C', 'id' => '8'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($first);


$newarray = array($first['ACCOUNTS']['description'] =>
            array($first['HEADERS']['description']  =>  
                array($first['COLUMNS']['description'] =>
                    $first['COLUMNS']['id'])));


print_r($newarray);
```

You then end up with:

```
Array
(
    [ACCOUNTS] => Array
        (
            [description] => A
        )

    [HEADERS] => Array
        (
            [description] => B
        )

    [COLUMNS] => Array
        (
            [description] => C
            [id] => 8
        )

)
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => Array
                (
                    [C] => 8
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: To be more specific I want to turn the following array into an associative one. The original array is indexed like [0],[1],[2],…[n]. The function I used was Set::combine of Cakephp but I could recreate all three levels of the desired associative array.